# How do I solve this : app = Flask(_name_) NameError: name '_name_' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I keep getting this error message on my command line.

```
app = Flask(_name_)
NameError: name '_name_' is not defined
```

How do i solve this ?

Comment: Have you set your `FLASK_APP` environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this minimal Flask app : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

> 2. Next we create an instance of this class. **The first argument is the name of the application’s module or package. __ name__ is a convenient shortcut for this that is appropriate for most cases.** This is needed so that Flask knows where to look for resources such as templates and static files.

so instead

```
app = Flask(_name_)
```

it should be

```
app = Flask(__name__) # name is wrapped with double underscores
```